# How to troubleshoot the spring-boot microservice that cannot respond to requests normally?

Tags: java, spring-boot, freeze

the main component version information that the application depends on is as follows:

```
[INFO] com.isli:com.isli.datacollection:jar:3.0.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.31:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.46:compile
[INFO] ...
```

The information of `jsatck -l` is as follows:

```
2023-10-16 15:46:02
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):

"HikariPool-1 connection adder" #9401 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5e0400d000 nid=0xc40 sleeping[0x00007f5e7eeb3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000f8ebabb0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"HikariPool-1 housekeeper" #9446 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5df0005000 nid=0x203f waiting on condition [0x00007f5e746ce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1249f50> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"HikariPool-2 housekeeper" #62 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5dd800e800 nid=0x2038 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e773f2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e2034400> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"HikariPool-2 connection adder" #9466 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5dd8036800 nid=0x2c5 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e74cd2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000f8ee35c0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"HikariPool-4 housekeeper" #9444 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5da4006800 nid=0x757d waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7c656000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1f5f5c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"HikariPool-4 connection adder" #9465 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5dd8037800 nid=0x22f waiting on condition [0x00007f5e744cc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000f8ee2e80> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"logback-8" #3615 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc797000 nid=0x6717 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e86781000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-7" #3614 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc795000 nid=0x6716 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e775f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-6" #3503 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d20008800 nid=0x5166 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e777f6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-5" #3502 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d20006800 nid=0x5165 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e749d1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-4" #1901 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc6d3000 nid=0x1b6d waiting on condition [0x00007f5e771f0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-3" #1900 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc6d2800 nid=0x1b6c waiting on condition [0x00007f5e774f3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-2" #1899 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc6d2000 nid=0x1b6b waiting on condition [0x00007f5e747cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-1" #1898 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc6d1000 nid=0x1b6a waiting on condition [0x00007f5e776f5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e6cb1e20> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"logback-1" #9448 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d6001e800 nid=0x6b98 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7dead000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f8edc1e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DiscoveryClient-12" #9439 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d78005800 nid=0x43cc waiting on condition [0x00007f5e743cb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1e8bc40> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DiscoveryClient-8" #9431 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d4000a000 nid=0x4257 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e770ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1e8bc40> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-2" #8071 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5de4003000 nid=0x27a4 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e76aeb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1e8b9f0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-2" #3643 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d98002000 nid=0x712a waiting on condition [0x00007f5e772f1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1e8b440> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0" #98 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5dec001000 nid=0x2385 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e74dd3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dbf238> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"PollingServerListUpdater-1" #80 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d8c001800 nid=0x2082 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e765e8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1edc458> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"pool-1-thread-1" #79 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc827800 nid=0x2081 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e766e9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e15f3470> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Okio Watchdog" #78 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc81e800 nid=0x2080 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5e767ea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.awaitTimeout(AsyncTimeout.java:338)
    - locked <0x00000000e2033dc0> (a java.lang.Class for okio.AsyncTimeout)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog.run(AsyncTimeout.java:313)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"PollingServerListUpdater-0" #74 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc73e000 nid=0x2072 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e76fee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1edc458> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RibbonApacheHttpClientConfiguration.connectionManagerTimer" #70 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ddc3f0800 nid=0x2070 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5e7fffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000000e1edd308> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #61 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed400a800 nid=0x1fdb waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-10" #55 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed62a4800 nid=0x2033 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e778f7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-9" #54 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed62a3000 nid=0x2032 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e779f8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-8" #53 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed62a1000 nid=0x2031 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e77af9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-7" #52 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed629f800 nid=0x2030 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e77bfa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-6" #51 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed629d800 nid=0x202f waiting on condition [0x00007f5e77cfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-5" #50 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed629c000 nid=0x202e waiting on condition [0x00007f5e77dfc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-4" #49 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed629a000 nid=0x202d waiting on condition [0x00007f5e77efd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-3" #48 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed6298800 nid=0x202c waiting on condition [0x00007f5e77ffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-2" #47 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed6296800 nid=0x202b waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7c151000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-nio-9026-exec-1" #46 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed6295000 nid=0x202a waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7c252000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dde1a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    ...

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" #45 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed6293800 nid=0x2029 runnable [0x00007f5e7c353000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000e1e205d0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
    - locked <0x00000000e1e205c0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000e1e20498> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:298)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"pool-8-thread-1" #44 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed6272800 nid=0x2028 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7c454000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e202aa70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0" #43 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed6249000 nid=0x2027 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7c555000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1f5f728> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:764)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:695)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.borrow(ConcurrentBag.java:157)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:166)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:103)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:99)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1382)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:117)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000e1e686a8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"AsyncResolver-bootstrap-0" #40 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed61fb000 nid=0x2024 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7ca58000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1dbf718> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Eureka-JerseyClient-Conn-Cleaner2" #39 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed61da000 nid=0x2023 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7dfae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e1fcbac8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java2D Disposer" #37 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5dfc291800 nid=0x201b in Object.wait() [0x00007f5e7d359000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e128e7a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000000e128e7a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"container-0" #33 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed5d5d000 nid=0x2017 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7e8af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer$1.run(TomcatWebServer.java:182)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"spring.cloud.inetutils" #31 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5e10207000 nid=0x2011 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7eab1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e13c7088> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-7" #28 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5e2c013000 nid=0x200e waiting on condition [0x00007f5e7efb4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e105b5c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.LatencyUtils.PauseDetector$PauseDetectorThread.run(PauseDetector.java:85)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-3" #22 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4f1b800 nid=0x2004 waiting on condition [0x00007f5e84b8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e055b3c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-2" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4f1a000 nid=0x2003 runnable [0x00007f5e85f68000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.poll(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.access$600(LinuxWatchService.java:47)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:314)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #17 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4389800 nid=0x1fff runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread11" #16 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed437c800 nid=0x1ffe waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread10" #15 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed437a800 nid=0x1ffd waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread9" #14 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4378000 nid=0x1ffc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread8" #13 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4376000 nid=0x1ffb waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread7" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4374000 nid=0x1ffa waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread6" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4371800 nid=0x1ff9 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread5" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed436f800 nid=0x1ff8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread4" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4365800 nid=0x1ff7 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4363800 nid=0x1ff6 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4361000 nid=0x1ff5 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed435f800 nid=0x1ff4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed435c800 nid=0x1ff3 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed435b000 nid=0x1ff2 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4328800 nid=0x1ff1 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5e87bfa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000000e001e0f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4323800 nid=0x1ff0 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5e87cfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000000e0021a50> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed431c000 nid=0x1fef runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4020000 nid=0x1fdd runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4022000 nid=0x1fde runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4023800 nid=0x1fdf runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4025800 nid=0x1fe0 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4027000 nid=0x1fe1 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4029000 nid=0x1fe2 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed402a800 nid=0x1fe3 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed402c800 nid=0x1fe4 runnable 

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed402e000 nid=0x1fe5 runnable 

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4030000 nid=0x1fe6 runnable 

"GC task thread#10 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4031800 nid=0x1fe7 runnable 

"GC task thread#11 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4033800 nid=0x1fe8 runnable 

"GC task thread#12 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4035000 nid=0x1fe9 runnable 

"GC task thread#13 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4037000 nid=0x1fea runnable 

"GC task thread#14 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed4038800 nid=0x1feb runnable 

"GC task thread#15 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed403a800 nid=0x1fec runnable 

"GC task thread#16 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed403c000 nid=0x1fed runnable 

"GC task thread#17 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed403e000 nid=0x1fee runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5ed438c800 nid=0x2000 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1656
```

access any api of the application using `curl` in the command line, for example: `curl http://127.0.0.1:9026/actuator/env`, unable to respond, no timeout has been reached, and it hangs there. Using `netstat` to troubleshoot, the `curl` request status is `ESTABLISHED`. How can I find out where the problem is?

Comment: jstack pid to look which thread is blocked

Comment: I'm sorry, but due to the length of the output from jstack, I've condensed it (by removing some duplicate information) and included it here; No threads with a blocked state were found;

Comment: do you import the spring-boot-start-actuator and set `managent`, and you can try use the `@RestControllerAdvice` to catch there is some exception

Comment: Of course, I'm just giving an example here; In fact, requesting any API has the same result.

Comment: I can't see any exception through the log. I suspect that the request hasn't arrived at the controller yet.

Comment: You can consider becoming a controller without any business to see if it returns results. If there is no feedback yet, I have no idea :(

Comment: I try to use `curl -I`, the behavior is the same, `-I` is not going to go business logic;